# How do I authenticate users of a web-app to access GCP data relevant only to them?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have spent 3 days researching this problem and cannot find a solution or similar use case that shows how to solve the problem, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I am creating a web-app that uses Google Cloud Storage and Bigquery. A user registers on the web app and then can upload data to Cloud Storage and Big Query. Two users could be from the same company and therefore should be able to view the same data - i.e. Jack and Jill work for company A and if Jack uploads a massive dataset via this app, Jill should also be able to view it later.

Another scenario will be I have two completely separate clients with users using this web-app. If users from Company A upload data, users from Company B should not be able to view Company A's data, and vice versa. But users from the same company should be able to view the data within their company.

Currently, I have an app that works for a single company. This has a React front-end that uses Firebase for authentication. Once the user is logged in, they can use the app which sends off API calls to a Flask back-end that does some error checking and authentication checking and then fires off an API call to GCP. This uses a service account and the key is loaded as an environment variable in the environment in which the Flask app is running.

However, if Company B want to use the app now, both Company A and Company B will be able to see each other's data and visualize it through the app. In addition, they will be sharing a project (I would like to change this to allocate billing more easily to have each client have their own project).

I ultimately want to get this app onto Kubernetes and ensure that each company is independent of each other, however, do not want to have to have separate URL's for every company using the app. Also, I want to abstract GCP away from the client. I would prefer to authenticate a user based on their login credentials and then they will be given access to their GCP project (via my front-end) accordingly.

I thought about perhaps having separate service keys for each client and then storing the service key info in Firebase, while using the respective keys for API calls but not sure this is best practice. It is however the only strategy I can think of.

If anyone could provide some help or guidance it would be very much appreciated. This is my first GCP project and have not been able to find any answers on GCP, SO, Google Groups, Slack or Medium.

Thanks,
TJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if all, welcome on GCP! It's an awesome platform, very powerful and flexible. But not magic.

Indeed, the use case that you describe is specific to your business logic. GCP provides told for securing access for user and VM(through service account) but not for customer. Here you have to implement your own custom and authorisation logic, with a database (I don't recommend bigquery for website, the latency is too high) to list three users, the companies where they work, the blobs of each company...

Nothing is magic and your use case specific.
If you want to discuss more about which component to use and to start, no problem. Let a comment.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks for the response. Whilst I understand that BQ will have some latency, I am attempting to visualise datasets that exceed 10's of millions of points. I have queries that run aggregations and Level of detail algorithms to ensure the client browser can handle the data. Should I be using a normal authentication service (Firebase in my case) and using OAuth to then access GCP? I am struggling to understand how to use a service account as it will not know anything about which user is on the front-end. That means it will provide the front-end user with all datasets to pick from.

Comment: Bigquery have about 1s of latency for each query. Thereby, if you have to request to bigquery on reach user click, the user will wait too much! If he has to wait on a specific action it's acceptable. If, in addition, he is aware about the amount of data of the specific action, he will be impressed!!

Comment: I understand. So then for applications that want to take advantage of BigQuery, is the answer to write queried data out into something like Cloud Spanner? I feel like in order to use GCP you need to use all of it and it is quite challenging to build an app using GCP as the back end. The main frustration is still how to map a service account to a user.

Comment: Think that Google have specialized product. Bigquery is for analytics. Spanner is a world-wide distributed relationnal database. Cloud SQL is managed relationnal database. What is your need? Today, we use cloud SQL as buffer of bigquery for having low latency on website. No need of world wide class. But, in some months things could change. BI engine is a cache for bigquery for having low latency request for data studio. More connector should happen, maybe for backhand...

Comment: About your frustration, don't map service account to user. You are limited to 100 service account or project. Service account is made for machine to machine authentication.

Comment: Welll it is an analytics application. Simply viewing vehicle performance in a GeoSpatial manner. Although the query performance is ok for now it is always nice to tune it for even faster response.

Comment: In terms of the authentication part, I may have not explained it well. I want this to be a multi-tenant application for two companies with many users in each. I want to be able to assign either an admin role of a user role to the users. If i use pure service accounts (as I  am now) then all users get the same permissions once they logged into my app (bad). I also do not want to force them to have Google accounts. So it needs to be service accounts. It is a catch22 it seems. The only way out of this I can see if by mapping a service account to the permission level of a user in my app somehow.